# 80s book about mermaids in a cove or bay

Tags: story-identification, mermaids

Seeking title and author please: I read a cool library book in the 80s in Australia about a family who goes to a holiday house on a cove and they find mermaids there. They keep it secret.
Im 100% sure the title doesn’t have the word mermaids in it, but I’m pretty sure it has the word “cove” or “bay”. Young adult/teen.
I think the book was English or American.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember any details of the cover art, or any names?  If you remember anything else about the book, even if was paperback vs. hardcover, please [edit] that information into the question.

Comment: FWIW, I searched ISFDb for novels with "bay" or "cove" in the title published between 1940 and 1989, without finding any mermaid stories.

Comment: Not a match, but I am reminded of ["The Case of the Mother-in-law of Pearl"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63303) by Avram Davidson, one of the Doctor Estherhazy series.